# Swift array reduction: cannot use mutating member on immutable value

Tags: swift, functional-programming, immutability

I have the following code that attempts to consolidate redundant elements of an array:

```
var items : [String] = ["hello", "world", "!", "hello"]

var mutableSet = Set<String>()

items.reduce(mutableSet, combine: { (set: Set<String>, element: String) in
    return set.insert(element)
})
```

`set.insert(element)` gives me the error `Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'set' is a 'let' constant`. What's wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: `let uniqueItems = Set(items)` would be simpler ...

Comment: Great solution, Martin. My code actually doesn't use literals but objects, so Set(items) doesn't work. Is that because I need to define the equality operator for the objects? Edit: just saw they need to be hashable

Comment: @coolcade, yes, your objects need to implement the [`Hashable`](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/protocol/Hashable/) protocol (which in turns implies that your objects are `Equatable`).

Comment: I realized I was comparing objects when I meant to be comparing an enum they store, so your solution works for what I'm trying to do. Thanks, Martin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Swift, collections are value types. Value-typed variables declared with `let` (as implicitly are function parameters) cannot be modified. Additionally, your closure returns nothing, so `reduce` will probably not succeed.

I believe that `reduce` is not the best-suited tool for this task. Consider this `for` loop instead:

```
var set = Set<String>()
for element in items { set.insert(element) }
```

Another even simpler option would be to use the `unionInPlace` method:

```
var set = Set<String>()
set.unionInPlace(items)
```

Even better perhaps, create the set straight from the collection:

```
var set = Set<String>(items)
```

Comment: Thanks for your better solution, zneak. I modified the original post to create mutableSet before the reduce call and added a return call, but the error still comes up.

Comment: @coolcade, that's because your modification didn't address the fact that function parameters (and closure parameters) are implicitly immutable. Besides, even though you now have a return statement, `set.insert` still does not return a value and can't be used with `reduce` (or at least, not that easily).

Comment: Ah, I see both of your points, the parameter is immutable and insert returns nothing. I'm now using the Set<String>(items) solution in my code and it works perfectly. Thanks, zneak.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the OP's code is that the accumulator in the reduce is immutable so it won't allow you to use the mutating function insert().

A tidy solution is to define an non-mutating equivalent to insert() called inserting() in an extension to Set as follows.

```
extension Set {
    //returns a new set with the element inserted
    func inserting(_ element: Element) -> Set<Element> {
        var set = self
        set.insert(element)
        return set
    }
}
```

Now we can write the reduce as follows

```
var items : [String] = ["hello", "world", "!", "hello"]

let set = items.reduce(Set<String>()){ accumulator, element in
    accumulator.inserting(element)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'set' value returned is a constant. This is important as it is the accumulator, which represents the values that have accumulated, thus far. It should not change in your closure.

Here is an example from a project I'm working on at the moment, where I want to find all of the unique **performers**, across many theatrical **performances**. Notice how I am using union, which does not modify the constant value 'performers', but instead consumes it to produce a new value.

```
let uniquePerformers = performances.reduce(Set<Performer>(), { (performers: Set<Performer>, performance) -> Set<Performer> in
    return performers.union(Set(performance.performers))
})
```